# Beacons shows Abandoned status as both my device and beacons are plaeced together

Tags: android, android-ibeacon, beacon

I am using Kontakt beacons and their sample code.

Everything is working fine, but having one question I want to know during foreground and background scan beacon shows Abandoned notification too weather my phone and beacon are placed together.

I have to perform some operations when device is out from beacon range, but due to this I am having some difficulties.

```
protected abstract void onBeaconAppeared(final int info, final IBeaconDevice beaconDevice);

protected abstract void onRegionAbandoned(final int info, final IBeaconRegion region);

protected abstract void onRegionEntered(final int info, final IBeaconRegion region);

protected abstract void onScanStarted(final int info);

protected abstract void onScanStopped(final int info);
```